# Find radius of convergence for the given sequence: $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've been trying to realize how to find the radius of convergence for this sequence:

$$\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}x^n$$

I know that it converges for any given $x$, but can someone explain me why or how to get to this solution?

Thanks

Comment: It converges for any given $x$, as you say. So the radius of convergence is $\infty$.

Comment: Ratio test gives $r=\infty$.

Comment: If you want to be exact, just use the definition formula of convergence radius, with the aid of Stirling formula.

Comment: I know that but I'm kinda confused about how solving this, can someone please show an example?

Comment: @Zhanxiong Stirling formula? Nothing so complicated is needed

Comment: @FigureItOut Write the series as

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n, \quad\text{ where } a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}x^n$$

Then by the ratio test, the series converges if $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| < 1$$ Calculate that limit.

Comment: @SimonS Sure, I understand for this example the ratio test is more handy than direct calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ratio test states that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converges as long as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1.$$
So we can use the ratio test here:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|-\frac{x^{n+1}n!}{x^n(n+1)!}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x}{n+1}\right|=0.$$
Thus, it doesn't matter what $x$ is, the series converges.

Another way to do this, if you know about Taylor series, is to recognize that this is the Taylor series for $e^{-x}$, which has no singularities anywhere, so this series converges everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This series is equivalent to:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}$.

This series is equivalent to $e^{-x}-1$. This clearly has no singularities. Therefore the radius of the disc of convergence is infinite.